# Object Size in SOS Debugging C#.Net

Tags: c#, debugging, sos

```
class Book
{
    public int ISBN { get; set; }      
}

void Method() 
{
  Book book = new Book(); 
  // Break and verify in SoS Debugging.
}


   !dumpheap -type Book
   PDB symbol for clr.dll not loaded
   Address       MT     **Size**
   00c6b76c 009b7f2c       **12**      
   total 0 objects
   Statistics:
   MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
   009b7f2c        1           12 GCTest.Book
   Total 1 objects
```

How the size of object here is 12 bytes . It contains only one integer property. sizeof(int) = 4 bytes remaining 8 bytes ? (object instantiation). Can anyone shed some light.

Comment: If you are interested in some in-depth details, here is MSFT's in depth description of runtime object layout, as of .NET 2.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S15

Comment: Good one. I have read that. Great stuff from Jeff ritcher in CLR via C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every reference object has two extra field appended :

`Object type ptr`  : 4 bytes (*ddress of a memory (AppDomain specific) that contains a structure holding the Method Table of the Reference Type for which the object is instantiated or points to*)

`Sync block adress` : 4 bytes   (*sync block address and points to a location in a process-wide table that contains structures used for synchronizing access to instances of Reference Types*)

More info Check the memory layout in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti#4)

Answer (score 1):

You have on top of the object strucure 8 bytes of information:

4 bytes for *object reference*

4 bytes for *syncblk*: a special memory block used for syncronisation. In *your* specifica case it will be set to 0, as your object doesn't partecipate in any sync operaiton.

In other words:

> <--SyncBlock(4bytes)--> <--ObjectReferece(4bytes)--> <--your object
>   data-->

For more information have a look at:

[Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)